# Не могу понять, как написать манипулятор для оператора ввода

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть класс, который отвечает за установку двунаправленного соединения между процессами(через pipe), ввод в stdin дочернего процесса и вывод через его stdout производятся с помощью операторов << и >>.

Мне нужно сделать так, что была возможно как читать stdout целиком, так и по частям. Для этого я хочу написать манипулятор, в параметры которого можно будет указывать максимальный размер доступный для чтения за раз.
К сожалению, не могу найти как это правильно сделать... Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот перегрузка оператора ввода:

```
conepipe& operator >> (conepipe& this_pipe, std::string& buffer)
{
    char buf[1024];
    while (ssize_t size = read(this_pipe.fdout_,&buf, 1023))
    {
        buf[size] = '\0';
        buffer+=buf;
    }
    return this_pipe;
}
```

Comment: оператор ввода возвращает ссыльку на строку?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Да, мне нужно получить вывод дочернего процесса в строку

Comment: По хорошему он должен возвращать ссылку на `conepipe`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, обычно их перегружают так, но я не вижу в этом смысла в данной ситуации, но буду рад, если мне его объяснят. Тогда придется хранить прочитанные данные внутри класса и сздавать метод для доступа к ним ?

Comment: @DenverToha Не понял. Вы же передаете строку по ссылке, так что ее не обязательно еще и возвращать. Возвращать `conepipe&` нужно для того, чтобы можно было писать несколько операторов в ряд: `foo >> a >> b;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял, спасибо